# Sending Multiple Emails : Run-time error "440": The object does not support this method

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that sends multiple emails with attachements. The macro crashes with the error 440, by the line of .Send . Sometimes it crashes after 50 sent emails, sometimes after 30. What can be wrong?

I tried it firstly with 20 files and it worked perfectly. 
Really dont know what is the case, havent found answer on the internet.

```
Set rangepro = Worksheets("Mappings").Range("f2:f" & rangeprojects)

For Each cell In rangepro                        'loops every project in rangepro, this name is used later in the filter to generate the files

    Worksheets("27a Report").Range("A1:au" & range27a).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value

    'Select only the visible cells in active sheet
    Worksheets("27a Report").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

    '~~> Source/Input Workbook
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
    'Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    With wbO

        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

        ActiveSheet.Name = "27a Report"

        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                     SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Call GeneratePivots.CreatePivot1

        Call checkiftravel

        ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Path = "\\wrofs1\sd&m\OnePMO\01.Services\03.Operations\05.Industrialization\Tools\27a\" & f & d & "\"

        .SaveAs Filename:=Path & cell.Value & d & "-NBTReport.xls", FileFormat:=56

        .Close

        'send the email
        eSubject = Worksheets("Mail").Range("c2").Value
        eBody = Worksheets("Mail").Range("c5").Value
        eOnBehalf = Worksheets("Mail").Range("c26").Value
        'eAttach = Range("f27").Value

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        OutApp.Session.Logon
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = eOnBehalf
            .To = cell.Offset(0, 1)
            '.cc = ccAll
            .Subject = eSubject
            .body = eBody
            '.Attachments.Add eAttach
            .Attachments.Add Path & cell.Value & d & "-NBTReport.xls"
            .Display
            .Send
        End With

    End With

Next cell
```

Comment: Probably because You are creating 20+ sessions of Outlook and same amount of emails - not closing them. Try to add in the end of every loop `Set OutApp = Nothing set OutMail = Nothing` or create Outlook app once before loop.

Comment: Isnt the email being closed after .Send?

Comment: Yes, it is closed, but resetting variables is ( `= Nothing`) is good approach, I think.

Comment: I tried, but still same error :(